# Struct with interface type fields

Tags: google-app-engine, go, struct

Why is it I can't have this in golang?

```
type EventDefinition struct {
     Name string
     EventProperties interface{}
}
```

Where EventProperties can be one of may types of structs, each struct with different fields. The idea is to have an EventDefinition with EventProperties

```
type Party struct {
     Location string
     Hour string
}
```

or

```
type Wedding struct {
     Bride string
     Groom string
     Hour string
}
```

or

```
type Graduation struct {
     Location string
     Graduate string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. The problem was not related to this issue, the problem was

```
Location     : event.Party.Location.(string),
```

At some point in my implementation I was doing this when Location was a nil interface{}, hence the blowup.

As a response to this, it is possible to do what I mentioned.